# how do i match just spaces and newlines with python regex?

Tags: python, regex

how do i match just empty spaces including newlines with python regex?

```
hereissometext
    thereisspacepreceding
```

Basically trying to match all the space between the two groups of text.

Comment: I hate to say it... But.. What have you tried?

Comment: Mostly, have you read the [`re`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) Python documentation? You will find a clear answer there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're looking for a matching group for the whitespace + newlines, [here you go](http://rubular.com/r/QJJvcitEbv).

```
(\s+)
```